# Нужна ли запятая в сложноподчиненном предложении между однородными придаточными

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, спп

Нужна ли запятая между однородными придаточными (да и однородны ли они?) в следующем предложении, в позиции, отмеченной вопросительным знаком

> Мне отрадно было увидеть, что другие крестьяне просили по пятнадцать
> рублей за мешанинник, а мой отец просил по двадцать {,???} и при этом
> продавал быстрее всех.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) *Мне отрадно было увидеть, (2) что другие крестьяне просили по пятнадцать рублей за мешанинник, (3) **а мой отец просил по двадцать и при этом продавал быстрее всех.***

Это СПП с двумя изъяснительными однородными придаточными (2) и (3), причем придаточное включает **однородные сказуемые** *просил* и *при этом продавал*.  Запятая не ставится при наличии одиночного союза И.

**1. Пояснение**

[**ПРИ ЭТОМ**, *союз и наречие*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_642)

(1) **Союз**. Синтаксические конструкции, присоединяемые союзом «при этом», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. *Яковлев сел в кресло, закинул ногу на ногу, при этом обнаружились его красивые носки*. В. Шукшин, Мнение.

(2) **Наречие**. Не требует постановки знаков препинания. *Он при этом крякнул и махнул рукой*. И. Гончаров, Обыкновенная история.

В нашем случае однородные сказуемые соединяются **союзом И**, запятая не ставится, а ПРИ ЭТОМ – это наречие (а не союз).

**2. Примечание.**

Можно рассмотреть предложение с тремя однородными придаточными: (1) *Мне отрадно было увидеть, (2) что другие крестьяне просили по пятнадцать рублей за мешанинник, (3) а мой отец просил по двадцать, (4) **и при этом** у него покупали чаще.*

Я считаю, что семантика значительно **не изменится**. Противительный союз А объединяет придаточные (3) и (4) в **одну смысловую группу.**

**Интонация** второго варианта предполагает наличие паузы, логически последнее придаточное будет **подчеркнуто.**

Comment: Спасибо! Я воспользуюсь вашим советом из примечания, такой вариант, кажется, точнее всего передает смысл. Только поставлю не "чаще", а "охотнее", так лучше, на мой вкус.

Answer (score 3):

**Мне отрадно было увидеть, что другие крестьяне просили по пятнадцать рублей за мешанинник, а мой отец просил по двадцать и при этом продавал быстрее всех.**

Указанная запятая не требуется.
Здесь мы разбираем простое предложение в составе ССП: *"...мой отец просил по двадцать [рублей] и при этом продавал быстрее всех"*. Здесь однородные сказуемые *"просил"* и *"продавал"*, соединённые сочинительным союзом *"и"*.

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> Он уже строил планы на будущее и при этом не решался не то что к
> Марине как-то поприставать, а даже поцеловать Марину он боялся (Сальников "Петровы в гриппе...").

Comment: Тоже хотел написать об однородных сказуемых и ненужности запятой, а также о возможности рассматривать "и при этом..." в качестве присоединения, если делать особое ударение на "двадцать" с выраженной паузой после него.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец технически часть с "и при этом" может быть отделена тире, как присоединительная конструкция, но тогда теряется смысл. В присоединительной конструкции не может быть ключевой для предложения информации, и тогда получается, что персонажу отрадно было увидеть, что другие крестьяне просили по пятнадцать рублей за мешанинник, а его отец просил по двадцать. А суть-то не в том, что отец просил дороже, а в том, что продавал быстрее.

Comment: Да, согласен. Присоедиение здесь ни к чему, а логическое ударение и небольшая пауза могут быть чисто произносительными. //  Я тут неоднократно призывал участников отмечать вопрос, на который они отвечают (особенно вопросы новичков). Вот пишу и Вам. Если ты берешься за вопрос, появляется возможность еще раз освежить в памяти свои знания, углубить их, а может, и пересмотреть, открыть новые аспекты и, в конце концов, получить за это баллы.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец да, это верно. Я не в малой степени пришёл на этот форум для того, чтобы был повод и учиться, и постоянно повторять уже изученное. Если нет практики, то теряются знания и навыки. Да и в целом мышление становится менее острым, дебелеет.

Comment: @Nektoid  Вы по семантике определяете отсутствие спорной запятой. А вот с точки зрения грамматики мы можем ставить запятые в однородном придаточном предложении?  Не будут ли они затруднять понимание всей структуры СПП?  Другими словами, может ли придаточное иметь собственную присоединительную конструкцию, или она будет относиться ко всему предложению?

Comment: @Sharon только при отсутствии сочинительного союза. *Мне отрадно было увидеть, что другие крестьяне просили по пятнадцать рублей за мешанинник, а мой отец просил по двадцать, при этом продавал быстрее всех.*

Comment: @Nektoid Могу я поставить запятую, если не буду учитывать семантику (присоединительный союз "и притом")?  Присоединение будет относиться к придаточному или ко всему СПП?

Comment: @Sharon не знаю. Я думаю, что запятую можно поставить, только если последняя часть превратится, в свою очередь, в отдельное придаточное: *"Мне отрадно было увидеть, что другие крестьяне просили по пятнадцать рублей за мешанинник, а мой отец просил по двадцать, и притом у него покупали чаще".*

Comment: Да, здесь будут три придаточных, причем два последних связаны союзом А. Хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: @Sharon погодите-ка, союзом "а"? Я полагал последним придаточным "у него покупали чаще". Нет?

Comment: @Nektoid Я дам ответ с полным грамматическим анализом, так удобнее делать, чтобы обсуждение было яснее.